# Read NTLM-authenticated feed with SimplePie or similar?

Tags: sharepoint, rss, ntlm, simplepie, rss-reader

Inside our firewall, I am trying to use SimplePie to work with RSS feeds from various platforms used by my company. I am not having any luck reading SharePoint RSS with SimplePie. Our SharePoint is authenticated with NTLM, and I suspect that SimplePie does not support NTLM, which would explain my problem.

Can anyone confirm that SimplePie does not support NTLM?

And if SimplePie does not support NTLM, is there a similar toolkit I can use to read our SharePoint RSS feeds? Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, SimplePie does not support NTLM authentication.

The best way to handle this (in my opinion) is to subclass the `SimplePie_File` class and customise it, then set it via [`$feed->set_file_class()`](http://simplepie.org/api/class-SimplePie.html#_set_file_class). For an example of how to do this, take a look at [WordPress' custom HTTP class](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/class-feed.php#L57), which maps the SimplePie interface to WordPress' HTTP classes.